How can i run cookie.click() and click() function simultaneously?
count = 61
is_5_minutes = False

minutes = 0


def click():
    global minutes
    for sec in range(1, count):
        time.sleep(1)
        if sec == 60:
            click()
            minutes = +1
        elif sec % 5 == 0:
            if current_price >= time_machine_price:
                time_machine.click()
            elif current_price >= portal_price:
                portal.click()
            elif current_price >= alchemy_lab_price:
                alchemy_lab.click()
            elif current_price >= shipment_price:
                shipment.click()
            elif current_price >= mine_price:
                mine.click()
            elif current_price >= factory_price:
                factory.click()
            elif current_price >= grandma_price:
                grandma.click()
            else:
                curser.click()


while not is_5_minutes:
    cookie.click()
    click()

In this code, it should keep clicking the cookie until 5 minutes and simultaneously check all the conditions and act according to it. I tried using time.time() still it's not working.

This is not a Selenium-related question so I removed the [selenium-webdriver] tag.

Your click() function never returns so your while loop never goes more than one loop and the predicate is never evaluated again.
